# iOS - Local authentication change fail message

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin, touch-id

There's a LA service in my app that uses TouchID pretty much as usual. The problem is that I want to change what is written on the alert that shows up when touchId authentication is prompted. First it shows what I declare in reason string, than if auth fails, it only changes title to 'Repeat', but body stays the same.

Is there any chance to change the alert's body for a different message when auth fails? I tried changing reason string but no effect.

This project is created using Xamarin, but Objective-C/Swift code is also acceptable. Thanks in advance!

UPD: here's my code:

```
if (context.CanEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, out authError))
            {
                var myReason = new NSString("Use your finger to authenticate");

                replyHandler = new LAContextReplyHandler((success, error) =>
                {
                    InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        if (success)
                        {
                            Login();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            myReason = new NSString("Nope try again");

                            switch ((long)error.Code)
                            {
                                case (long)LAStatus.TouchIDLockout: // 5 times wrong, TouchID is locked system-wide
                                    {
                                        var alert = new UIAlertView("Sorry", "Exceeded and blocked message", null, "OK");
                                        alert.Show();
                                        touchIdButton.Hidden = true;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case (long)LAStatus.AuthenticationFailed: // 3 times wrong
                                    {
                                        var alert = new UIAlertView("Sorry", "Exceeded message", null, "OK");
                                        alert.Show();
                                        touchIdButton.Hidden = true;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case (long)LAStatus.UserFallback: //Enter Passcode
                                    //no UserFallback for now
                                    break;
                            }

                        }
                    });
                });
                context.EvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, myReason, replyHandler);
```

Comment: Please paste your code here.

Comment: sure thing! sorry, got too excited :) added code. it uses InvokeOnMainThread() as there is some asynchronous stuff inside Login(). not sure if it matters for changing alert's body though (i'm not a big specialist in C#)

Comment: just change myReason string in every failure blocks. You will get desired value.

Comment: I tried changing it before switch (like 'change in any case that is not success') and it had no effect. maybe i'm changing it wrong? updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no API for changing the Reason in between the auth process.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514176-evaluatepolicy

> **localizedReason**
>
> The app-provided reason for requesting authentication, which displays in the authentication dialog presented to the user.

This means: What you are trying is not intended by Apple. The reason for requesting the auth stays the same independent from the failed try count. In other words: Your reason for requesting hasn't change after the first failed attempt.

---

**Advertisement section**

If you are interested in a cross platform solution for fingerprint auth, have a look at my plugin :) https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint

Comment: I came here because the plugin by smstuebe asks for a `reason` param in the `AuthenticateAsync` method. In the testing for Android, I passed string.Empty for the reason and the UI looked cleaner. When testing on iOS, there was an exception thrown because of the missing reason. After providing a reason, iOS was fine too.