# Unable to localize Face Id popup for non-matching face

Tags: ios, objective-c, face-id

It seems like Face Id is ignoring `localizedFallbackTitle` and `localizedReason`. However `localizedCancelTitle` is working fine. Does anyone know how to get it work?

**My code:**

```
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
if ([context respondsToSelector:@selector(setLocalizedCancelTitle:)]) {
    context.localizedCancelTitle = [Language get:CANCEL alter:nil];
}

if ([context respondsToSelector:@selector(setLocalizedFallbackTitle:)])
{
    context.localizedFallbackTitle = [Language get:TRY_AGAIN alter:nil];
}

NSError *error = nil;
if ([context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication error:&error]) {
   [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication
   localizedReason:[Language get:AUTHRNTICATE_USING_YOUR_FACE alter:nil] reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
   //code
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Nonmatching face popup]

I want to localize everything on this popup if possible.

**Note:** Attached screenshot is taken on simulator. I have also checked
it on real device but the result is same. Also, for Touch id it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48564925/ios-local-authentication-change-fail-message?answertab=votes#tab-top), there is no API for changing the Reason in between the auth process.

> **localizedReason**
>
> The app-provided reason for requesting authentication, which displays in > the authentication dialog presented to the user.

You can use [BiometricAuthentication](https://github.com/rushisangani/BiometricAuthentication) to show your message.

```
BioMetricAuthenticator.authenticateWithBioMetrics(reason: "", success: {

    // authentication successful

}, failure: { [weak self] (error) in

    // do nothing on canceled
    if error == .canceledByUser || error == .canceledBySystem {
        return
    }
    
    // device does not support biometric (face id or touch id) authentication
    else if error == .biometryNotAvailable {
        self?.showErrorAlert(message: error.message())
    }

    // show alternatives on fallback button clicked
    else if error == .fallback {

        // here we're entering username and password
        self?.txtUsername.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    // No biometry enrolled in this device, ask user to register fingerprint or face
    else if error == .biometryNotEnrolled {
        self?.showGotoSettingsAlert(message: error.message())
    }

    // Biometry is locked out now, because there were too many failed attempts.
    // Need to enter device passcode to unlock.
    else if error == .biometryLockedout {
        // show passcode authentication
    }

    // show error on authentication failed
    else {
        self?.showErrorAlert(message: error.message())
    }
})
```